# SQLite database: Is there a way to put same data into 2 tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I tried to make my data to be inserted in 2 Tables within the same time. The 1st table is for the users and the second one is for the admin. I also inserted additional 2 columns for the admin for later usage. I just want to know how can I insert data in 2 tables within the same time. Whenever i run my app, the 2nd table doesn't have the data that I inserted.

```
package com.radixappointment.radix;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseInfo extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

/*Information Database*/
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "information.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "information_table";
public static final String ADMIN_NAME = "admin_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "COMPANY_NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "CLIENT_NAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "CONTACT";
public static final String COL_5 = "TIME";
public static final String COL_6 = "STATUS";

public DatabaseInfo(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, COMPANY_NAME TEXT, CLIENT_NAME TEXT, CONTACT TEXT)");
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ADMIN_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, COMPANY_NAME TEXT, CLIENT_NAME TEXT, CONTACT TEXT, TIME TEXT, STATUS TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ADMIN_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String Company, String Client, String Contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, Company);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, Client);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, Contact);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
public boolean insertDataAdmin(String Company, String Client, String Contact, String Time, String Status) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, Company);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, Client);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, Contact);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, Time);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, Status);
    long adminresult = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (adminresult == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor getAllDataAdmin() {
    SQLiteDatabase dbadmin = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor admin = dbadmin.rawQuery("select * from " + ADMIN_NAME, null);
    return admin;
}
}
```

Comment: Bump can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have specified the wrong table and are thus trying to insert **all rows/data** into the **user**'s table as opposed to the **admin** table. This additional attempt will fail, but be trapped, as the time based columns will not exist in the **user** table.

To fix this, in the `insertDataAdmin` method, change :-

```
long adminresult = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
```

to be :-

```
long adminresult = db.insert(ADMIN_NAME, null, contentValues);
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I didnt notice that :0